# Centering and removing white space from a SVG in an enclosing div

Tags: svg

I am facing difficulty in stretching a SVG in the X-axis, so that there is no white space visible on either side. Also, I want the point (marked in red circle in the attached picture) to touch the starting of the second div with background color of black. I have tried changing the viewbox values, but I am not able to achieve the desired result.

The below is my code.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%
}

body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.example {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;  
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
}

.section-two {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 3000 1750">
        <path d="M2987.34,2.895l-2984.74,-0l0,1224.16l671.731,426.733l2313,-426.733l0,-1224.16Z" style="fill:#f8be46;"/>    
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="section-two">

</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQAc4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that to happen, you need to do two things:

1. Make sure that your `viewBox` is correct. It needs to match the dimensions of your `<path>`. It currently doesn't.
2. Add the following attribute to your SVG to turn off the automatic aspect-ratio-preserving scaling that SVG does.

   ```
   preserveAspectRatio="none"
   ```

If we check the bounding box of your path, we get the values:

```
x: 2.600
y: 2.895
width: 2984.740
height: 1650.893
```

So that is what your viewBox needs to be set to, if you want the path to touch all four sides of the SVG's parent container.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%
}

body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.example {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;  
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
}

.section-two {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <svg viewbox="2.6 2.9 2984.7 1650.9" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M2987.34,2.895l-2984.74,-0l0,1224.16l671.731,426.733l2313,-426.733l0,-1224.16Z" style="fill:#f8be46;"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="section-two">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, When I see the SVG on smaller screen sizes, the angle of the graphics is getting changed. This is because preserveAspectRatio is turned off. And If I remove the preserveAspectRatio attribute from the code, then on smaller screen sizes, the SVG is getting centered on the div with white spaces on both top and bottom. So what is the solution for maintaining the aspect ration without getting any whitespaces?

Comment: Try `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice"`